# Como corregir la hora en el TimeStamp

Tags: java

Tengo este código en java, que me esta metiendo la hora mal, por ejemplo, son las 11:00 AM y la variable me muestra 12:00 AM, es decir, media noche, como puedo corregir esto para que me ponga la hora actual.

Primero obtengo la fecha de del JDateChooser y se pasa a la variable date.

```
java.util.Date date = txtFecha.getDate();
```

Despues en la variable fecha, se le pone la hora que se supone es la del sistema.

```
Timestamp fecha = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Sonara algo básico, pero apenas estoy aprendiendo a manejar Java. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Mack, podrías mostrarnos como instancias el objeto **Date**?.

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta, el obejto date se llena desde un JDateChooser

Comment: Por lo que contás, parecería que la hora del sistema, no coincide con la hora local, está bien configurada?, pregunta, lo probaste varias veces o solo una?, si fueron varias, siempre te da la diferencia de 13 hs?, podrías sacar por consola la fecha que te devuelve el **JDateChooser**, creo que lo más probable, es que no tenga hora, sino solo fecha, entonces al convertirlo, **TimeStamp** lo pone en cero (medianoche).

Comment: Una cosa que note cuando investigaba el error es que en la cadena String de la variable tenía estas letras CTD o algo parecido, supongo que eso marca la zona horaria

Comment: el formato que me devuelve es así: **2023-07-26 16:13:27.784**, no me contestas ninguna de las preguntas que te hice.... jjiji

Comment: La actualización de las tablas de zona horaria en Java es independiente del sistema operativo. Actualiza Java, o en su defecto dinos que JRE/JDK usas para decirte cómo actualizar dichas tablas. Si es en México, es muy probable que necesite tal actualización.

Comment: Soy de Mexico, estoy usando el jdk 1.8, @MarcePuente cuando extraigo el dato del jdatechooser me da el dato así: 26/07/2023 03:22:04 PM, despues cuando pasa por el timestamp me lo devuelve así: 26/07/2023 03:22:04 PM

Comment: Se te han mezclado, los dos son iguales, mi recomendación, sigue la guia de @Sal, o bien lee [esto](https://chgonzalez.blogspot.com/2016/05/actualizar-informacion-de-zona-horaria.html)

Comment: Eso ya lo hice, y sigo teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: Hay varias implementaciones de JVM/JDK, hay propietarias, free y opensource; para decirte la configuración correcta necesitamos saber el proveedor (Oracle, IBM, OpenJDK, etc) y la versión exacta. Ejemplo: Oracle Java SE 8u381.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final logre resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    java.util.Date date = txtFecha.getDate();
    Instant ins = date.toInstant();
    Instant horN = ins.minusSeconds(3600);
    Timestamp fecha = Timestamp.from(horN);
```

Al menos en lo que consigo comprender como mejorar esta parte para que me tome la hora real que tengo en el sistema operativo.

Comment: Muy bien, después de 48 hs (creo) puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada!!

Comment: No deberías hacer eso, si lo ejecutas en una JVM bien configurada el usuario tendrá resultados inesperados. Tapas un hoyo mientras abres otro.

Comment: Lo probe en otra computadora y no dio ningun problema, aun asi, estoy tratando de buscar una mejor solución para ese problema, porque sería volver a cambiar el código cuando termine el horario de verano, antes de hacer eso intente configurar el JVM para el horario pero nada me resulto.

Answer (score 0):

Debe haber algún conflicto con el "horario de verano" o es lo que percibo.
Encontré esta solución, no sé si es la más eficaz, pero solventa el problema.

```
LocalDateTime hora_sistema = LocalDateTime.now();
int hora = hora_sistema .getHour(); 
int minutos = hora_sistema .getMinute();
int segundos = hora_sistema .getSecond();
hora = hora - 1; //le resté una hora únicamente, ya que obtenía lo mismo que tú
System.out.println(""+hora+":"+minutos+":"+segundos);
```

Mi salida es la siguiente:

**12:25:48**